# strange variable behavior when meeting if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

i'm writing a **JS** code which reads an **XML file** and extract required info from it, *I want to find the name of a selected item*, this is my code:

```
function initialize() {
    ct = $('menu').children().length;

    for(cati=0;cati<=ct-1;cati++) {
        cats[cati] = $('menu').children().eq(cati).prop('nodeName');
    }

    var selecteditem = $(".selected").text();

    for(j=0;j<=cats.length;j++) {
        if(selecteditem == realnames[j]) {
                selecteditem = cats[j];
        }
    }

    $("#gallery").empty();
    alert($('menu').find(selecteditem).prop('nodeName'));
}
```

here in my code when alerting using the last stmt there are two scenarios, the first one is when the `if statement` condition **doesn't achieved**, and in this case the alerting gives me the desired result(the selected item), but when the `if statement` condition **achieved**, the alerting gives me `undifined` although i'm certain that the `cats[j]` is an element in the XML file.

Comment: where is `realnames` being assigned?

Comment: Looks like you're comparing objects, which is never going to return `true`.

Comment: Can you show us some of your XML file so we see what you're trying to do?

Comment: @JonathanM it's another array has the same length (it's derived from the first array)

Answer (score 1):

At least your for loops look weird

```
// Always use them like this
for (var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
    // do stuff with arr[i]
}
```

See, in your first for loop you got

```
for (var i = 0;i <= arr.length-1;i++){
    // do stuff with arr[i]
}
```

And in the second

```
for (var i = 0;i <= arr.length;i++){
    // do stuff with arr[i]
}
```

You should **stick to one way** of declaring `for loops`. There is not need to reduce from `arr.length` if only you use `<` operator to compare the i and arr.length. Not `<=` operator. In your second loop you're going out of the bounds of the array.

---

Another weird thing you got there. When you loop through the cats array.

```
for(j=0;j<=cats.length;j++) {
    if(selecteditem == realnames[j]) {
            selecteditem = cats[j];
    }
}
```

You are referencing the `realNames[]` array with the iterator `j` of the `cats[]` array. While in theory this may work if you always got the same amount of `cats[]` and `realNames[]` in 2 distinct arrays and you never sort them and they always really map 1 to 1 with each other but this approach is vulnerable to error, this doesn't look like a reliable way of going about it. Plus of course the for loop goes out of bounds. Like mentioned earlier.

Comment: the realnames[] derived from cats[] and forsure has the same length, also i think it's not about the for as the for loops running normally and the problem happens only when hitting the if condition of the second loop

Comment: i think the matter is in cats[j]

Comment: @MRefaat Look, the loops aren't running normally. Unless you want them go out of bounds. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/WQRwy/

Comment: well, i got your point, but still the problem after declaring the vars inside the for